# AG GRID - get lines on the current page with pagination and infinite model

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, vue.js, ag-grid

I want to know how to get all the nodes or rows that are in the current AG-Grid pagination.

The closest I got to this was `this.gridApi.getRenderedNodes()`, but it does not bring all the lines from the current page.

Framework website: https://www.ag-grid.com/.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the data of your table with the API method `getModel()`. Make sure to use the filtered data. Then, you can use the method `paginationGetPageSize()` to find out the currently configured page size. Together with `paginationGetCurrentPage()` you can then extract the subset of rows which are on the current page.

See also the documentation: https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/javascript/grid-api/

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example based on [ssc-hrep3's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66284632/2965919):

```
const pageSize = this.gridApi.paginationGetPageSize()
const currentPage = this.gridApi.paginationGetCurrentPage()
const filteredData: MyData[] = []
this.gridApi.forEachNodeAfterFilter((n) => {
  filteredData.push(n.data)
})
const startIndex = currentPage * pageSize
const endIndex = startIndex + pageSize

const pageData = filteredData.slice(startIndex, endIndex)
```